# Gradle build failed with Kotlin, Scala and Java

Tags: java, scala, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

I have a project written in Java, Scala and Kotlin.

But when I build this project in Gradle, it error with message:

```
11:19:51: Executing task 'build'...

:compileKotlin
Using Kotlin incremental compilation
e: F:\Code\Project\Avalon\src\main\kotlin\avalon\group\Execute.kt: (3, 19):             
Unresolved reference: Flag
e: F:\Code\Project\Avalon\src\main\kotlin\avalon\group\Execute.kt: (10, 18):     
Unresolved reference: GroupMessageResponder
e: F:\Code\Project\Avalon\src\main\kotlin\avalon\group\Execute.kt: (13, 2): 
'doPost' overrides nothing
e: F:\Code\Project\Avalon\src\main\kotlin\avalon\group\Execute.kt: (35, 23): 
Unresolved reference: Flag
e: F:\Code\Project\Avalon\src\main\kotlin\avalon\group\Execute.kt: (38, 2): 
'getHelpMessage' overrides nothing
e: F:\Code\Project\Avalon\src\main\kotlin\avalon\group\Execute.kt: (40, 2): 
'getKeyWordRegex' overrides nothing
e: F:\Code\Project\Avalon\src\main\kotlin\avalon\group\Execute.kt: (42, 2): 
'instance' overrides nothing
:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Compilation error. See log for more details
11:19:53: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

Those errors are all about 'Unresolved reference', and those 'reference' are all written in Scala or Java.

But run this project in IDEA **works fine**.

I thought this was caused by Gradle compile Kotlin first, which should compiled in last, so those 'reference' could not be found.

And this is my `build.gradle`: [build.gradle](https://github.com/Ray-Eldath/Avalon/blob/master/build.gradle)

**UPDATE:**

A part of output of `gradle clean testClasses --info`:

```
...SKIP...
> Task :compileKotlin
Using Kotlin incremental compilation

e: F:\Code\Project\Avalon\src\main\kotlin\avalon\group\Execute.kt: (3, 19): 
Unresolved reference: Flag
e: F:\Code\Project\Avalon\src\main\kotlin\avalon\group\Execute.kt: (11, 18): 
Unresolved reference: GroupMessageResponder
...SKIP....

> Task :compileKotlin
[KOTLIN] deleting F:\Code\Project\Avalon\build\classes\kotlin\main on error
[KOTLIN] deleting F:\Code\Project\Avalon\build\classes\kotlin\main on error

:compileKotlin (Thread[Task worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 15.981 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option 
to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 24s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
```

**Full output posted** [**here**](https://gist.github.com/Ray-Eldath/adbb6947e3c286ccf56f4e53eaaebc04).

Comment: You have to be careful when you use more then one not-Java-JVM language. What class is `Unresolved reference: Flag` of? Is it `scala`? Can you run `./gradlew clean testClasses --info` and post the output

Comment: @guenhter   This error happened when `Kotlin` refer to `Scala`, when execute `gradle build`. And the output of `gradle clean testClasses --info` now posted...

Comment: Can you please post more of the output. Best would be from the top. I have an idea what the problem is, but I need more log.

Comment: @guenhter I had post full log on [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Ray-Eldath/adbb6947e3c286ccf56f4e53eaaebc04)

Comment: :) ok than it's clear. See my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you have are the different languages.

**Some Kotlin and Java**

Let's assume you just have kotlin and java.
Than you can access from (`->` means A accesses classes of B)

```
kotlin -> java 
java -> kotlin
```

The reason you can do that, is because during the compilation (`compileKotlin`) Kotlin take care of this *crossCompilation*/*jointCompilation*/*whatever-other-name* between those two languages.

---

**Kotlin and Scala (one direction)**

But if you have the case:

```
kotlin -> scala
```

than you must consider the the following:
when `compileKotlin` runs, it compiles all `.java` and `.kt` files to `class` files, but non of the `.scala` files (because it doesn't know anything about `scala`). 
When you now access `scala` classes from `kotlin`, than you must first compile those `.scala` classes, to ensure that the `compileKotlin` compilation process find those `.class` files for a successful compilation.

You can define that `scala` must run before `kotlin` with e.g.

```
compileKotlin.dependsOn compileScala
```

---

**Kotlin and Scala (both directions)**

So good so far, but the problem is, when you have

```
kotlin -> scala
scala -> kotlin
```

Because this scenario is not working.

You need to compile the `scala` classes first, to successfully compile the `kotlin` classes (see description above). But on the other hand, you need the `kotlin` classes to be compiled, to successfully compile the `scala` classes.
That's a problem.

The solution would be, that one of the languages allows *jointCompilation* for all of the languages (but this will never happen).

So for two JVM languages, where both are not `Java`, you must decide, which direction of access is allowed. But you can't allow both directions of access.

In such cases, it often helps, to put the logic into a `java` class, and access this `java` class instead of the e.g. `scala` class.

The problem is also the same for e.g. `groovy`, `java` and some other jvm language, like in the post https://discuss.gradle.org/t/kotlin-groovy-and-java-compilation/14903/10

Comment: Many thanks first. But are there any other solutions exist? Just to make sure I do have to rewrite all the Scala code, and this project could compile and run in IDEA **normally**.

Comment: I had the same issue in my old company with `groovy` and `scala`. It works in the IDE (not sure why; IntellJ is a magical piece of software anyway) but with gradle it is absolutely deterministic and reasonable why this can't work (unless we have a super compiler which allows to cross compile all the JVM languages)

Comment: I had finished rewrite and this certainly helps, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The missing link to let Scala call Kotlin code would be to add the following in build.gradle

```
compileScala.classpath += files(compileKotlin.destinationDir)
```

Based on https://discuss.gradle.org/t/kotlin-groovy-and-java-compilation/14903/3